# Use Resource file variable in MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, resx

I have created resx file in Content Folder where this is available for model but when I tried to access it from view it doesn't show up.

Folder structure like below:

[image]

Where I am trying to access the data like this:

```
  <p>@Resources.Resources.lblHomeDesc1</p>
```

But it doesn't render the data and settings are `CustomTool=PublicResXFileCodeGenerator, BuildAction=Embedded Resource`. 
How to use resx file data in MVC view? Does we need to add reference in web.config? Is there something else I am missing to add?

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved the by creating new folder for Resource files folder structure below :
[image]

and updated `Custom Tool Namespace = Resources`.